# Is this function continuous at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by:

$$f(x)=\left\{{\begin{matrix}1-x\ {\mathrm  {\:\:when}}\ x\notin \mathbb{Q}\\x-1\ {\mathrm  {\:\:when}}\ x\in \mathbb{Q}\end{matrix}}\right.$$

Is this function continuous at $0$? For me it's pretty clear it's not. But my professor added a hint: "Be careful!". Should I worry?

Comment: It's not continuous at $0$, but it is continuous somewhere!

Comment: To answer the second question in the post: No you shouldn't worry. I refer you to the movie _Bridge of Spies_, where the question comes up repeatedly.

Comment: Only cont@1 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written, it is definitely not continuous at $0$. Because $f(0)=-1$, while 
$$
f\left(\frac{\sqrt2}n\right)=1\ne-1\qquad\frac{\sqrt2}n\to0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

study the  sequence $f(\frac1n)$ and the sequence $f(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n})$.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't. Take an irrational sequence $x_n\to 0$ then $f(x_n) = 1-x_n \to 1$ but $f(0) = -1$.